# Combining arrays based on keys from another array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I want to combine two arrays like this:

1st array:

```
   array( "ATTENDED"        => 1,
          "TENTATIVE"       => 2,  //
          "REJECTED"        => 3,
          "OUTSTANDING"     => 4,  
          "ACCEPTED"        => 6
        );
```

2nd Array:

```
  array ( 1 => 29, 
          4 => 30, 
          6 => 47 
        );
```

I want to get the results like this:

```
  array ( 'ATTENDED' => 29, 
          'OUTSTANDING' => 30, 
          'ACCEPTED' => 47
        );
```

2nd array is flexible. I can flip keys and values.

or better yet:

```
   array( "ATTENDED"    => 29,
      "TENTATIVE"       => 0,  //
      "REJECTED"        => 0,
      "OUTSTANDING"     => 30,  
      "ACCEPTED"        => 47
     );
```

I know there must be a simple solution. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr1 as $k1 => $v1) {
    $arr1[$k1] = isset($arr2[$v1]) ? $arr2[$v1] : 0;
}
```

edit-
This is without an explicit loop, although I don't think this is really better, but maybe cooler though.

```
$mapped = array_map(function($valFromArr1) use ($arr2) {
    return isset($arr2[$valFromArr1]) ? $arr2[$valFromArr1] : 0;
}, $arr1);
```

I can't think of a sane way to just use pure php functions.

Comment: Possible without loop? I don't need 0, if its only possible with loop. First output is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $labels = array( 
          "ATTENDED"        => 1,
          "TENTATIVE"       => 2, 
          "REJECTED"        => 3,
          "OUTSTANDING"     => 4,  
          "ACCEPTED"        => 6
        );

    $values = array(
          1 => 29, 
          4 => 30, 
          6 => 47 
        );

   $results = array();

   foreach ($labels as $label => $id) {
       $results[$label] = array_key_exists($id, $values) ? $values[$id] : 0;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I there must a solution without loop!

Comment: In another language I would suggest a functional approach using `map` or similar, but PHP's level of support for such things makes solutions that use them somewhat clunky.

Comment: This is the output I get:
      Array ( [ATTENDED] => 1 [TENTATIVE] => 1 [REJECTED] => 1 [OUTSTANDING] => [ACCEPTED] => )

Comment: See edited answer.  someone dropped their Perl into my PHP code. :)  But with the fix, my answer is essentially the same as @chris's, so you should accept his before mine.