# PHP: create an array from values in two arrays based on matching keys

Tags: php, arrays

### The Problem

I would like to create a new associative array with respective values from two arrays where the keys from each array match.

For example:

```
// first (data) array:
["key1" => "value 1", "key2" => "value 2", "key3" => "value 3"];

// second (map) array:
["key1" => "map1", "key3" => "map3"];

// resulting (combined) array:
["map1" => "value 1", "map3" => "value 3"];
```

### What I've Tried

```
$combined = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $map)) {
        $combined[$map[$key]] = $value;
    }
}
```

### The Question

Is there a way to do this using native PHP functions? Ideally one that is not more convoluted than the code above...

This question is similar to [Combining arrays based on keys from another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286186/combining-arrays-based-on-keys-from-another-array). But not exact.

It's also not as simple as using `array_merge()` and/or `array_combine()`. Note the arrays are not necessarily equally in length.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_intersect_key()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php).
Something like that:

```
$int = array_intersect_key($map, $data);
$combined = array_combine(array_values($map), array_values($int));
```

Also it would be a good idea `ksort()` both `$map` and `$data`.

Comment: Why is `ksort()` a good idea? I assume you think it will optimize performance?

Comment: Well, just to play safe... so when `array_combine()` runs it will combine them in proper keys orders... Just to play safe.